# How to parse formula of html table cell to acting like Excel, using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, html-table

I am looking for a way to make html table acting like excel using Javascript (Jquery preferred). Here are my problem. I made a table like this:

```
 <table>
       <tr>
          <td id="A1">10</td>
          <td id="B1">10.5</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td id="A2">5</td>
          <td id="B2" formula="A1+B1+A2"></td>
       </tr>
 </table>
```

Every td has an id, some of those tds are added a formula attribute. And I wanna to calculate those formula， give the value of formula to the td.

In the table above, here, I wanna assign the **B2** value **25.5(B2=A1+B1+A2)**.

Look like this:

```
<td id="B2" formula="A1+B1+A2">25.5</td>
```

Can anybody give me a clue? Thanks.

PS: Here are some resource that I found, but they do not solve my problem

1. [Spreadsheet-like formulas on the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930016/spreadsheet-like-formulas-on-the-dom)
2. http://zaach.github.com/jison/docs/

---

Thanks a lot @palindrom. I finally solved my problem based on your answer.

Here is my code:

```
    $("td[formula]").each(function(){
        //1 get formula attribute
        var formula = $(this).attr('formula');

        //2 use regex to make expression, with the surpport of "A122"， "AB1" and more
        var expression = formula.replace(/([A-Z]+[0-9]+)/g, "parseFloat(\$('#$1').html())") ;

        //3 eval the expression
        var result = eval( expression );

        //4 set the value
        $(this).html(result);
     });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should work for simple math, didnt try:

```
$("td[formula]").each( function() {
  this.html( eval( this.attr("formula").replace(/[a-z][0-9]/g, "\$('#$0').html()") ) );
} );
```

**Edit:**
If you have functions like sum in the formulas, implement them as javascript functions and they should work too.

Comment: Is there a way to limit this to only Maths operations, to avoid unwanted code to be executed?

Answer (score 3):

even if this too late, try this plugin https://github.com/xsanisty/jquery-calx

I have develop it using jison parser in its core, it will parse the formula in the data-formula attribute just like you want

Answer (score 0):

[This is a html table](http://papou.byethost9.com/notes/hosting/) I wrote in which a formula is computed for each line (see iframe source).
The formula is written in JavaScript (as complex as can be) in which [abc] is replaced with the value of cell with id=abc (weights from the header)  and {abc} with the text in cell from the same column in that line.
The columns are sortable
The weights are modifiable by the user and they are remembered in a cookie.

Hoping this can help.

Comment: Hi Papou, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)